# I want to know if my below understanding on wcf security is right

Tags: c#

1. I want to know if my below understanding on wcf security is right :
   For using username as client credential, when using security modes : transport or 
   message or transportwithmessagecredential, a service certificate is a must.
2. I also want to know , if I do-not want to configure a service certificate and I don't 
   want to use windows client credentials , is there a way to enable security on wcf (using 
   any binding)?
3. I know that using message security in a domain server based network, by default uses
   windows credentials. But in a non domain (Plain LAN setup) , is there a way to enable 
   security in WCF without a service Certificate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only proper way to secure WCF is to use certificate. There is not any other way to mak4 communication secure. But you do not have to buy a certificate you can generate your own.